# Solving ODE for emptying water tank, exclude branch with complex infinity

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, piecewise

I'm trying to simulate a water tank. The dynamic of the system should be described by:

> DSolve[{y'[x] == Piecewise[{{-Sqrt[y[x]], 0 < y[x]}}, 0.],
> y[0] == 10}, y[x], x]

[image: Blockquote]

An infinite object ComplexInfinity might occur if you look at the -Sqrt[y[x]] term outside of 0 < y[x], however that branch should never be active under this condition.

[image]

So i don't under stand why Mathematica looks at those branches of the general solution where it is unable to compute the limit at the given points.

EDIT: Imposing the real number constraint gives the same solution as Daniel Huber however this solution stops when tank is empty. I want the solution to be `Piecewise[{{1/4 (40 - 4 Sqrt[10] x + x^2), x < 2*Sqrt[10]}}, 0]`.

#### How can i convince Mathematica to solve this problem in a way that gives me a constant solution after the water ran out of tank?

( I'm running Mathematika 11.3 )

Answer (score 1):

Remember, if not told otherwise, MMA assumes all variables to be complex. You have to specify that x is real and >=0:

```
DSolve[{y'[x] == Piecewise[{{-Sqrt[y[x]], 0 < y[x]}}, 0.], 
  y[0] == 10}, y[x], x, Assumptions -> {x >= 0}]
```

With this you get:

[image]

Comment: This note about assuming complexity is helpful, however i would want a solution that has constant 0 after 2Sqrt[10] Mathematica seems to solve one branch and then not continue.

The correct solution to the differential equation should be Piecewise[{{1/4 (40 - 4 Sqrt[10] x + x^2), x < 2*Sqrt[10]}}, 0]